# Creating bounding box for a polygon using Revit API in C#

Tags: c#, polygon, bounding-box, revit-api

I am trying to create a bounding box for any given ploygon using Revit API. Can someone help?

```
namespace Revit_SquarePlacement.Command
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    class cmd_Training : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet elements)
        {
            try
            {
                UIApplication UIAPP = commandData.Application;
                UIDocument UIDoc = UIAPP.ActiveUIDocument;
                Autodesk.Revit.DB.Document ActiveDoc = UIDoc.Document;

                //Creating Bounding Box

                Reference oRef = UIDoc.Selection.PickObject(Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection.ObjectType.Element);
                Element oLineEle = ActiveDoc.GetElement(oRef.ElementId);
                Line oLine = oLineEle as Wall;

                if (oWall != null)
                {
                    LocationCurve WallocCurve = oWall.Location as LocationCurve;
                    Line oLine = WallocCurve.Curve as Line;

                    XYZ LineStartPoint = oLine.GetEndPoint(0);
                    XYZ LineEndPoint = oLine.GetEndPoint(1);
                }
```

I tried finding the start and end point of a line and using that I tried getting min and max value of the line in order to get a bounding box. How should I move forward?

Answer (score 0):

[The Building Coder samples](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples) defines a method `ExpandTo` that can do what you require:

It is used and described here:

- [Curve Following Face and Bounding Box Implementation](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/04/curve-following-face-and-bounding-box-implementation.html)
- [GeoSnoop .NET Boundary Curve Loop Visualisation](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/04/geosnoop-net-boundary-curve-loop-visualisation.html)
- [Determining the Size and Location of Viewports on a Sheet](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/04/determining-the-size-and-location-of-viewports-on-a-sheet.html)
- [Vacation End, Forge News and Bounding Boxes](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/08/vacation-end-forge-news-and-bounding-boxes.html)
- [FilterRule Use and Retrieving Exterior Walls](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/05/filterrule-use-and-retrieving-exterior-walls.html)
- [Room Boundaries to CSV and WPF Template](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/01/room-boundaries-to-csv-and-wpf-template.html)
- [AI, Boundaries, Loops and RevitApiDocs 2020](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/05/ai-boundaries-loops-and-revitapidocs-2020.html)